# Sending a file using sockets (java) from a client to the server succeeds but the client freezes and does not exit the loop

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer

I run the server and client on separate cmd windows. The server prints out "Upload successful" and indeed the file gets uploaded to the server but the client freezes and i have to quit the client process using Ctrl+C. It seems to me that the client cannot break out of the while loop. Please tell me where i am going wrong?

(The code snippets are parts of much larger code body that i am writing to implement file read, write, read/write-lock, delete file etc from the server. Once a request to upload the file from the client is handled by the server I want the process to return to the command line menu i have incorporated with the client program[not shown below]. So it is important that the client returns to that user interface. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! )

Client side:

```
// initialized client and server connection made...

BufferedReader filePath = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String pathname = filePath.readLine();

try{
    File file_to_upload = new File(pathname);                               
    byte[] bytearray = new byte[(int) file_to_upload.length()];
    OutputStream os = client1.getOutputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file_to_upload));

    do {
        bis.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
        os.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
        os.flush();
        bis.close();
    } while (bis.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length)!= -1);
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
System.out.println("\n" + inFromServer.readLine() + "\n");

client1.close();
break;
```

server side:

```
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1];
InputStream is = server1accept.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("234rews");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
bos.close();
outToClient.writeBytes("Uploaded");
System.out.println("Upload Successful");
```

Comment: I don't understand your `bytearray`, you are just creating a `byte[]` of a particular size but there is nothing in it for the `bis` to read.

Comment: @noMad When the program is run and if a file is specified by the client, the file gets uploaded to the server. If there is nothing in the `byte[]` for the  `bis` to read how is the file getting uploaded? Thoroughly confused here...

Answer (score 4):

Both your copy loops are incorrect. The canonical way to copy between streams in Java is:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

At present you are doing extra reads and ignoring read() results and all kinds of other strange things. Use this code at both ends, with any buffer size greater than zero.

Comment: thanks. I am completely new to sockets programming and i started learning java just four days ago. May be that why I dont understand your answer completely. Can you please point out the "strange things" :D. Also which read results are ignored and which reads are extra?

Comment: The only read() result you *aren't* ignoring one way or another is the one in the do/while condition, which is also the extra one. If it doesn't return -1 it is immediately followed by another read() inside the loop, whose return value is ignored. So any data read by the extra read() is lost. In the server, you're only reading one byte for some reason, and you're ignoring the possibility of premature EOF.